# Shorthand index to get a cycle of a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I want to index all elements in a numpy array and also include the first index at the end. So if I have the array `[2, 4, 6]` , I want to index the array such that the result is `[2, 4, 6, 2]`.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.asarray([2,4,6])

# One solution is 
cycle = np.append(a, a[0])

# Another solution is 
cycle = a[[0, 1, 2, 0]]

# Instead of creating a list, can indexing type be combined?
cycle = a[:+0]
```

Comment: You have do some sort of concatenate of slice results, or use advanced indexing with an array that contains all parts.  A single basic index cannot reference discontinuous parts of the areay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possible solution:

```
a = np.asarray([2,4,6])
cycle = np.take(a, np.arange(len(a)+1), mode='wrap')
```

Output:

```
[2 4 6 2]
```

Comment: Thanks, `mode='wrap'` is exactly what I as looking for.